# Populate reactive form with date retrieved from ngrx store

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to populate a form with data from store, but whatever I try (setValue, patchValue), the form is still empty

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 public newsletterToEdit$: Observable<NewNewsletter> =
    this.store.selectNewsletterToEdit();

 public form = this.fb.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    subtitle: ['', Validators.required],
    message: ['', Validators.required],
    users: [''],
    groups: [''],
    searchedUsers: [''],
    searchedGroups: [''],
    allowReplies: [false, Validators.required],
    replyFrom: ['NONE'],
  });

ngOnInit(): void {
```

// this.newMessageForm.controls['title'].setValue('test title'); -> this works, it populates control with the string

```
this.newsletterToEdit$.pipe(
      tap((newsletter) => {
        console.log('newsletter to edit: ', newsletter);

        // this.newMessageForm.patchValue(newsletter) -> another try
        this.form.setValue({
          title: newsletter.title,
          allowReplies: null,
          groups: newsletter.sentToGroupCode[0],
          message: newsletter.message,
          replyFrom: 'NONE',
          searchedGroups: '1',
          searchedUsers: '2',
          subtitle: newsletter.subtitle,
          users: '3',
        });
      })
    );
}
}
```

I already checked, I do have data in store, but it seems that the console log is never logged so this means pipe(tap()) are not called

Comment: You need to subscribe `this.newsletterToEdit$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that ngrx selectors provide cold observables. Cold observables do not emit any data until someone subscribes to it.

Try using

```
this.newsletterToEdit$.subscribe(
 (newsletter) => {
        console.log('newsletter to edit: ', newsletter);

        // this.newMessageForm.patchValue(newsletter) -> another try
        this.form.setValue({
          title: newsletter.title,
          allowReplies: null,
          groups: newsletter.sentToGroupCode[0],
          message: newsletter.message,
          replyFrom: 'NONE',
          searchedGroups: '1',
          searchedUsers: '2',
          subtitle: newsletter.subtitle,
          users: '3',
        });
      })
});
```

in order to receive a value from it.

Please be aware that you should either unsubscribe from it or use an declerative approach (e.g. defining the form as an observable and using `async` pipe to subscribe to it).